Will supplying filtered water via a 1/2" pipe instead of a 1/4" tube cause trouble?
I have a reverse osmosis filter that uses 1/4" tubing for output. I currently have a 1/4" tube running across the surface of a wall to feed the R/O faucet.
If I run regular 1/2" pipe in the wall, and use this to transfer water from the 1/4" outlet to the 1/4" faucet, will I lose any pressure or flow? (e.g. wall mounting 5/8" OD compression to 1/4" OD compression valves each on each side)
Do you envision any problems with this setup? I just don't want to run 1/4" tube inside the wall (in part because I have all the parts to do this with 1/2" pipe).

Not an expert but IMHO - You shouldn't lose any appreciable pressure but you may end up with air in the 1/2" pipe, especially if it's horizontal. I'll let the plumbing experts chime in.

What rate of flow can your filter supply? What rate of flow will you be trying to draw from it?

@keshlam, I just measured it with the current setup - about a gallon per minute (it has a large pressure tank). I am hoping to maintain this flow rate.

I can't imagine how you would have a problem.
